# ¿Como puedo borrar el ultimo carácter de un textbox?

Tags: c#

```
     textBox1.Text = filasDatos["Codigo"].ToString();
```

[image: Números dentro del textBox]

mi formulario consta de dos botones, agregar y guardar, cuando el usuario aprieta `guardar` el `textbox` se habilita y muestra una cadena de tipo string con números `1.1.1.05` como ejemplo, es string porque contiene los puntos ¿como hago para que cuando el usuario apriete agregar solo pueda borrar el último número? En este caso el `5` y si intenta borrar los demás, el `1.1.1.0` no se lo permita. 
El botón agregar solo consta de este código:

```
         private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            //Boton Agregar
            textBox1.Enabled = true;
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
         }
```

Siento que el código debe ir en este botón o ¿iría en el botón de guardar?

Comment: ¿sabes como manejar las propiedades de un textbox y eventos? porque noto que no tienes el evento que ya te nombre,ademas ¿que editor de código manejas o IDE?

Comment: Visual Studio con windows form y `C#`, no supe como acceder desde el `button click` al evento que me dijiste. Ajuste la pregunta a como lo tengo. Al usuario apretar el `boton agregar` se habilita la caja donde están ingresados esos números.

Comment: Ok, tratare de darte de forma mas precisa una respuesta por medio de VS en cuanto pueda

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias estaré atenta.

Comment: Intente con lo que me dijiste anteriormente, pero no me deja ingresar números, no los borra, pero tampoco me los ingresa, estaré pendiente de tu respuesta.

Comment: Disculpa me equivoque en una cosa la condicion coloca solo el menor

Comment: ya lo corregi, disculpa error mio

Comment: gracias, si, el usuario puede añadir mas números. metí el código `filasdatos` dentro de un `private void` funcionará igual si ya no esta global?

Comment: Lo importante es el acceso a la variable **texto** de resto ya depende de la lógica que implementes, no olvides valorar mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero añade el **textBox** a la ventana y lo seleccionas

[image: lo primero]

después en la parte derecha de el **visual studio** donde aparecen las propiedades te aparecera algo como la imagen de abajo.

Nota: en el caso de que no te aparezca da click derecho a el **textBox** y da click en propiedades.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora como te señale en la anterior imagen hay un **rayo**  ahí es donde se encuentran los eventos de los componentes, como se muestra en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora le das doble click donde dice el evento de **keyPress** y el automaticamente te crea el evento, te aparecerá algo como lo que se ve en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora este evento lo que hace es que cada vez que una tecla se presione se llama a este evento, dentro de este evento ingrese un código que lo que hace es que valida el tamaño de un **String**  que fue instanciado al inicio de la clase como se ve a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora esta variable la inicializas cuando le den click a el botón **agregar**,con los datos que traes de la tabla con `filasDatos["Codigo"].ToString()` ya que es un variable **global** puedes acceder a ella desde cualquier método de la clase entonces con esta validación

```
 if (texto.Length<textBox1.Text.Length)
 {
    e.Handled = true;
 }

texto.Length<textBox1.Text.Length
```

esto valida el tamaño de la **variable** que es el estado **inicial** del textBox (osea cuando le asignas el valor al dar en el botón agregar) con el tamaño del texto del **textBox** (lo que tiene actualmente el textBox), en caso de que sean iguales o mayor va a permitir ingresar lo que sea necesario, pero si es menor (osea cuando borren) va a ignorar todo ingreso de datos por lo que siembre va a **ignorar** las teclas que sean presionadas por la siguiente linea.

```
e.Handled = true;
```

espero te quede un poco claro como funciona mi propuesta, lo que no se es si el usuario podrá añadir mas cosas o no, si solo puede añadir **"."** o **números** pero bueno suple lo esto aclara lo que tus dudas, aunque mi consejo es que te documentes como funcionan los eventos en c#, hay mucho material en youtube.

ah, y no olvides valorar mi respuesta, es la mejor forma de agradecer.

Comment: tengo ese textbox dentro de un private void, como hago para acceder a ese texto y guardarlo fuera para poder llamarlo con el evento del textbox?

Comment: crea una variable en el inicio de la clase, despues para optener el valor solo tienes que ir al componente en modo grafico y dale click, ve a las propiedades del texbos, una de sus propiedades es su nombre (name) si quieres cambia el nombre o dejalo como esta, entras al codigo de la ventana y dentro del evento, escribes el nombreTexbox.Text y ya ahi esta el valor que este escrito.

Comment: si es en la misma clase la accesibilidad de el componente no deberia ser problema pero si es el caso, hay una propiedad tambien que se llama Modifiers, por defecto esta private, cambia lo a publico si es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Lo siento sigo sin poder hacerlo `public void MostrarNodosText(TreeNode nodeData){
 DataRow filasDatos = mostrarNodosText.Rows[int.Parse(nodeData.Tag.ToString())];
                textBox1.Text = filasDatos["Codigo"].ToString();}`

cree la variable string fuera de este código e intente llamarla desde el evento del textbox, pero me salio error de objeto de instancia no declarada o algo asi, luego saque cree el int num fuera tambien e hice la comparacion dentro del evento pero me sigue borrando todo, yo solo quiero que se pueda borrar el ultimo numero y los demás los deje intacto

Comment: Primero que todo para poder ayudarte se necesitan 2 cosas el codigo de lo que estas haciendo, ya que puede que estes instanciando algo mal y segundo el error entero ya que sin el error no podemos ayudarte, te invito a que actualices tu pregunta para que sea mas clara.

Comment: Ya lo ejemplifique mejor, espero puedas ayudarme